# format AWS glue spark dataframe output

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I am trying to print my DataFrame on the log:

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "dev", table_name = "sellout_data_cw01_15_csv", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
....
dataframe = datasource0.toDF()
dataframe.show(10)
```

but the output is all messed up. How can I format it properly like a table with pandas in normal python?

Comment: can you try dataframe.show(n=10, truncate=False, vertical=True) ?

Comment: doesn't work as desired @PrabhakarReddy

Answer (score 1):

This is a Glue problem. You need to go into the CloudWatch logs of your job run to see it a bit more formatted.

[image]